# After edit of Grid cell, the value is overlapped with a zero

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

When I edit a cell in my grid, a zero ("0") is placed in the cell, overlapping the cell value. This zero does not show when the grid loads, and it does not save to the database when the update happens. If I navigate away and come back, the zero is gone. It only happens if I edit the cell; if I only click in the cell and initiate the inline editing, no zero appears. This happens in every cell, even the dates.
My page is an SPA.
This is the code that builds the grid:

```
function fnLoadStorageVaults(storageid) {

    var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: URL_GETVAULTS,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: { StorageID: storageid }
            },
            update: { dataType: "json", url: URL_UPDATEVAULTS, type: "POST" },
            destroy: { url: URL_DELETEVAULT, type: "POST" },
            create: { url: URL_INSERTVAULT, type: "POST" },
            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                return kendo.stringify(data);
            }
        },
        autoSync: true,
        schema: {
            model: { 
                id: "StorageVaultID",
                fields: {
                    VaultNumber: { type: "string", editable: true },
                    Section: { type: "string", editable: true },
                    Row: { type: "string", editable: true },
                    DateFrom: { type: "date", editable: true },
                    DateTo: { type: "date", editable: true },
                    WarehouseID: { type: "number", editable: true }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#VaultGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: ds
        , sortable: true
        , editable: true
        , navigable: true
        , columns: [
            { field: "WarehouseID", title: "Warehouse", width: "60px" }
            ,{ field: "VaultNumber", title: "Vault Nbr.", width: "60px" }
            , { field: "Section", title: "Section" }
            , { field: "Row", title: "Row" }
            , { field: "DateFrom", title: "Date In" }
            , { field: "DateTo", title: "Date Out" }
        ]
    });

}
```

[image: The Phantom Zero]

Comment: Which browser are you using? Which release of KendoUI? Could you try to reproduce it in JSFiddler or JSBin and share the link with us?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, the update was not working after all. The zero was the response from the server. Still curious behavior though.